# How do I configure cygwin cyg-get mirror sites?

Tags: cygwin, chocolatey

I installed [cygwin](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Cygwin) via Chocolatey on Windows, got [cyg-get](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cyg-get) package manager along with it to install packages.

Now that I want to install to packages like openssh, rsync. These are not getting downloaded since mirror site (mirror.kernel.org) is not responding and it's just paused on

> downloading setup.bz2

So the question is can I select mirror sites or configure them in cyg-get just like cygwin GUI ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've installed to the default location you should find the file in the following folder:

`C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\lib\cyg-get_####\tools\`

You will want to modify the file `cyg-get.ps1`

Look for the line containing: 
`$cygPackages -s ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin -P $package`

and modify the URL `ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin` to your preferred mirror

Answer (score 0):

The newer cyg-get package, released last week, allows you to specify a source if you don't want to use the default.

Answer (score 0):

Not even specifying the site worked for me, so what resolved was to open cygwinSetup executable and choose the mirror once. Then cyg-get auto selects my last mirror.